# Spring data redis get expiration time with crud interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

Is there anyway to get expiration time of redis model directly from spring data redis crud?

I have tried this but i can't get expirationTime.

```
@RedisHash(value = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String imageUrl;

    @TimeToLive(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    private Long expirationTime

   //getter setter...
}
```

it is quote from spring doc : [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data-redis/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations)

> > Annotating a property explicitly with @TimeToLive reads back the actual TTL or PTTL value from Redis. -1 indicates that the object has no associated expiration.

Why I can't get expiration time?
I don't want to use RedisTemplate for this.

Comment: What is the version of spring-data-redis?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk I can use any version if it will work